# what id differences between $this->{$spec} and $this->$spec?

Tags: php

also these two line:

```
$subForm = $this->{$spec}
$subForm = $spec;

public function prepareSubForm($spec)

{
    if (is_string($spec)) {
        $subForm = $this->{$spec};
    } elseif ($spec instanceof Zend_Form_SubForm) {
        $subForm = $spec;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Invalid argument passed to ' .
                __FUNCTION__ . '()');
    }
    $this->setSubFormDecorators($subForm)
    ->addSubmitButton($subForm)
    ->addSubFormActions($subForm);
    return $subForm;
}
```

Comment: you might mistake `$this->$spec` for `$this->spec`, while it is less likely with `$this->{$spec}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's said in the [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) part of the documentation:

> Curly braces may also be used, to clearly delimit the property name.
>   They are most useful when accessing values within a property that
>   contains an array, when the property name is made of mulitple parts

In this code there's no syntax-related reason to use `$this->{$spec}` instead of `$this->$spec`.

But:

- the first form may be more readable to some teams *(= enforced by the code conventions)*
- perhaps in the past there was an expression here (like `$this->{'_' . $spec}`), for example. And if you try to use an expression as 'variable property name', you need to use curve braces to delimit it.

As for difference between `$spec` and `$this->$spec`, it's more clear. This method can work with two types of its single argument:

- if `$spec` is of `String` type, it's viewed as the name of property; this property is what will be processed (decorated) later;
- if `$spec` is `Zend_Form_SubForm` object, this object will be decorated instead.